# can I define a array as preprocessor?

Tags: arrays, c, preprocessor

```
#define PUMP [0,1]
```

when I call a function like this:

```
for (index = 0;index < 8; index++)
{
get_motor_current(PUMP[index]);
}
```

The intent is to do get_motor_current([0][index]) and get_motor_current([1][index])

Thank you very much.

Comment: A Macro is direct text substitution done before compilation. So substitute the text and see if it makes sense. If it does for you, then I suggest to go back and refer to any basic C text book again.

Comment: `The intent is to do get_motor_current([0][index])` but what does `[0][index]` mean? I do not understand what is the intent.

Comment: what PUMP means?

Comment: `get_motor_current([0][index])` it is definitely not C. I think you need to start with a good C book

Comment: As far as `can I define a array as preprocessor?` that we be "no, preprocessor has no arrays". But you can define an array "using" preprocessor, and you can create an preprocessor function that will allow array-ish access to elements at compile time, and you can create something that can make the code you posted valid. But I do not understand what is the intent.

Comment: @Murali: Macros substitute preprocessor tokens, not text, and are not direct as macro replacement supports stringification and token concatenation operations.

Comment: Any advantage here over a `const` or `static`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by having the macro expand into a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PUMP ((const int[]){0, 1})

int main(void) {
    for (int index = 0;index < 2; index++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", PUMP[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: consider making the `PUMP` a constant: `((const int[]){0, 1})`. Btw the upcoming C23 standard will let it make `constexpr`

Comment: @tstanisl I was thinking that but wasn't sure it made a difference. The compiler should be able to tell if any of the uses modify it, and merge all the references if they don't.

Comment: The purpose was to disallow `PUMP[0] = 42`, what is likely not what OP indented. Though I might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you can't do what you're trying to do the way you're trying to do it.  All the C preprocessor does is perform direct text substitutions.  So, after preprocessing, your code snippet would look like:

```
for (index = 0;index < 8; index++)
{
get_motor_current([0,1][index]);
}
```

which is not valid C.

Also, square brackets `[]` are only used for indexing an existing array.  If you want to initialize an array with a list of values, you write a list of values enclosed in curly braces `{}` like so:

```
int some_array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

You don't need to define an array size here (i.e. say `some_array[4]`) because the compiler just counts the number of items in the list and does that for you.

Comment: Macros substitute preprocessor tokens, not text, and are not direct as macro replacement supports stringification and token concatenation operations.